# How to do this complicated query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
id
title
body
date

Tag:
id
title

Post_Tag:
id
id_post
id_tag

Comment:
id
id_post
body
date
```

There is a many to many relationship between post and tag.

I need to print in homepage this for the latest 10 posts:

```
<a href="post.php?id=ID_POST">POST_TITLE</a>

POST_BODY

<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_1"> TAG_TITLE_1 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_2"> TAG_TITLE_2 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_3"> TAG_TITLE_3 </a>

COMMENTS_NUMBER
```

What is the best query to do that ?

I have tryed this but it doesn't work well because I get multiple rows for each post:

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.date, t.title, t.id, COUNT(c.id)
             FROM post p
             LEFT JOIN post_tag pt 
             ON p.id=pt.id_post
             LEFT JOIN tag t 
             ON t.id=pt.id_tag
             LEFT JOIN comment c
             ON p.id=c.id_post
             GROUP BY p.title, p.id, p.date, t.title
             ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Then maybe we can go from there.

Comment: I have just inserted in the question what I have tried :D

Comment: Question: Why does Post_Tag table have a ID?

Comment: What is your expected result? As there are multiple tags for single post post data will repeat for each tag..

Comment: what's post_tag.id for?

Answer (score 3):

You probably wouldn't want to do this as a single query, but in theory you could do.

```
SELECT
    Post.id AS post_id,
    Post.title AS post_title,
    Post.body AS post_body,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags,
    COUNT(Comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.id = Comment.id_post
LEFT JOIN Post_Tag ON Post.id = Post_Tag.id_post
LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.id = Post_Tag.id_tag
GROUP BY Post.id
ORDER BY Post.date ASC
```

I haven't checked this as I don't have access to your data, but it should work. You'll need to manually split the tags, which would appear in the format of "ID|TITLE#ID|TITLE", but that's the only extra processing required.

Alternatively, you can avoid the GROUP_CONCAT for tags by splitting this workload between two separate queries:

```
SELECT
    Post.id AS post_id,
    Post.title AS post_title,
    Post.body AS post_body,
    COUNT(Comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.id = Comment.id_post
GROUP BY Post.id
ORDER BY Post.date ASC
```

From this, you'd store all of the individual post_ids, and use them in a second query as follows:

```
SELECT
    Tag.id,
    Tag.title
FROM Post_Tag
INNER JOIN Tag ON Post_Tag.id_tag = Tag.id
WHERE Post_Tag.id_post IN (**comma-separated list of Post IDs**)
```

This means you can do two queries, where otherwise you'd have to do one to get all of the posts, then another for EACH of those posts to retrieve the tags - THAT is an N+1 query, whereas what I propose above is a common way around the issue.

Comment: So you think that the best way is to do 1 query to get all posts and 1 query for each post to get all tags associated ?

Comment: I have just test it and in the "tags" column of the results, I get something like this: "[BLOB - 38B]".

Comment: @xRobot That would be an N+1 query, which is bad. You'd typically do one query to get all of the posts (and in your case, you could get the comment count at the same time), plus another query to get all of the tags for each Post ID you found in the first query. That keeps things a bit lighter.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand. Do you think that the best way is to do 1 single query ( like in your answer ) to get posts, comment number and tags OR N+1 queries ?

Comment: My original answer should work for a single query; my preferred method would be to do two queries - one to get all the posts, and another to get all of the related tags for each post.

Comment: and is this not more resource consuming to do N+1 queries ?

Comment: I'm going to add more clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to make a "posts with tags and comments"-system, with the following relationships
[image: relationships]

---

### One query to rule them all

As suggested by [Stephen Orr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604398/944301), you should do a `GROUP_CONCAT` for the tags to avoid duplicate posts. You'd also have to do some minor post processing to format the tags, unless you just want the tag title, but that's about it.

Here's an example

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.title,
    p.body,
    p.c_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', CAST(t.ID AS CHAR), t.title) SEPARATOR ';') AS tags,
    COUNT(c.ID) AS comments
FROM Post p
    LEFT JOIN Comment c ON p.ID = c.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Post_Tag pt ON p.ID = pt.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Tag t ON pt.id_tag = t.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.title, p.body, p.c_date
ORDER BY p.c_date DESC
```

Note that I use explicit type-casting on the tag id.

Here are some references to [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).